# jQuery UI Dialog Box give variable back to Box

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog

I have a script where I open a jQuery Dialog Box with a form. I send the values of the form via ajax to a php script. The php script save the value in a mysql database.

Everything work fine. But:

In the case, that something is wrong with the insert of mysql I will give a information back to the user. But not only "is wrong". I want give for example back "Already exists", "Wrong parameters" and so on.

How can give information back from the php script to tha jQuery Dialog Box?

My script looks like this:

```
  function openmodal() {   
      var $dialogContent = $("#create_mieter"),    
      mieterID = $("#mieterID"),
      snID = $( "#snID" ),
      mietwechsel = $("#datepicker"),
      zahlart = $("#zahlart");

      $dialogContent.dialog({
        height: "auto",
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        title: "Neues Mietverhältnis anlegen",
        close: function() {},
        buttons: {
            Sichern : function() {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "wohnungen_bearbeiten_mieter_sichern.php?act=create",
                data: "mieterID=" + mieterID.val() + "&snID=" + snID.val() + "&mietwechsel=" + mietwechsel.val() + "&zahlart=" + zahlart.val(),
                        success: function(response) {
                            alert("Show Success");                          
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert("Sorry something went wrong");    
                        }
                });
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
         Abbrechen : function() {  $( this ).dialog( "close" ); }
         }
      }).show();

      $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("z-index", "99999");
```

Comment: You need to return a response from the server to indicate there was an error. Format a `json string` to be sent back to the server in the `success: function(response)`. Then you can do `if(response.error){alert(response.error)}else{$(this).dialog('close')}`.

Comment: you are dealing with 2 separate types of errors. Error in AJAX communicating or returning unparseable data, or server side issues that you may need to send a message back such as failing to connect to db. They are not the same thing. Research AJAX status codes as a start for the error handler in jQuery. If your db fails to connect but server code doesn't crash... ajax success will still fire

Answer (score 0):

Its all about the 'response' right?

You want it to show you, for example, that the email the user chose, is already in use.
So, in the file you will request by ajax, you should do the validating, I did this once
My 'response' was like this:

it validates the email, and query it to see if it's in use, if it is, the response will be one, else it will be 0, and if another kind of error occur, the response would be the error itself

then back on the ajax function, I would validate the response, it works for me, hope it works for you

Sorry for the bad English, not native ;D